# Jmeter test fails for requests with firebase storage as back-end during image download

Tags: firebase, jmeter, firebase-storage

I am running a JMeter performance test for testing an application that uses firebase storage. I am using node as the backend and i am connecting to database using the firebase admin sdk.

The loading testing instantiated for thread count of 50 and duration of 1 second.

But some of the requests fail with the following error

```
Response code: 200
Response message: Embedded resource download error:https://storage.googleapis.com/****/*****?GoogleAccessId=firebase-adminsdk-*******&Expires=****&Signature=******* code:Non HTTP response code: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException message:Non HTTP response message: Remote host closed connection during handshake,
```

Is it because of the restrictions in the number of connections (upper limit) that firebase has ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My expectation is that you should not be load testing Firebase itself as it is not something you can efficiently control (unless you're a Google engineer who is load testing Firebase) as it might be the case you're exceeding [Free Quota](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas) or Google blocks suspicious traffic from your IP due to [DoS attack prevention mechanism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denial-of-service_attack)

My expectation is that you need to limit you load test to focus on **your application domain** only and no requests to Firebase should be made. In order to [exclude external domains from the embedded resources scope](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206732519-Excluding-Domains-from-the-Load-Test) you can add the following regular expression to "URLs must match" input of the [HTTP Requests Defaults](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request_Defaults):

```
^((?!storage.googleapis.com).)*$
```

[image: JMeter exclude embedded resources]

Comment: Thanks for the response. But I am designing a data intensive system and i would like to test if the data is retrieved within an expected period of time given for a certain number of requests.Is there a way to do that ?